# What does slash symbol mean in PARTITION BY ORDER BY (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I have legacy code and I've found this in window function:

`COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY stock_guid ORDER BY 1/0) row_cnt,`

What does **ORDER BY 1/0** mean? I can't find definition of slash symbol according to ORDER BY in documentation. I think it is not about divide operation. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is just a hack really. Same as order by NULL - you get an arbitrarily assigned value to each row, which *could* vary on subsequent executions. Order by 0/1 or even 1/0/1/0 works. Best use-case is for confusing future developers.

Comment: @Stu Thank you! So, "PARTITION BY stock_guid ORDER BY 1/0" and "PARTITION BY stock_guid" without "order by" are the same expressions?

Comment: COUNT() not needed in ORDER BY, so its usage makes no sense, and this clause can be removed from window definition.